# Facebook notifications do not open a browser window when clicked

Tags: macos, facebook, notifications

I am correctly getting notifications from Facebook in Mountain Lion's notification center, but when I click them expecting to be brought into the browser (Chrome is my default browser) to see the subject of the notification, nothing happens.
Instead, the notification just disappears from the notification center and I'm left there with no clue about what happened.

Is this normal behavior? If not, what should I do to correct it? I have also tried to change the default browser to Firefox but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also having troubles with the native Facebook alerts.
They just don't work as advertised, that's why I was searching in the web and found this article http://lifehacker.com/5943851/glow-for-fb-stuffs-unobtrusive-facebook-notifications-in-your-menu-bar

That app did it for me :) you click the Notification Center popups and you'll be redirected to the corresponding subject, *e.g. the photo, a comment or a message thread.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Mavericks, maybe because of the upgrade from Mountain Lion to Mavericks.

I solved this issue through deleting my Facebook Account from the **internet accounts** under **Settings**, restarting and then adding the Facebook account again.